# What's a good approach for updating millions of rows independently?

Tags: programming-practices, mongodb, big-data

I have a MongoDB database with millions of users in collection. An aggregation function returns millions of results with the following format:

```
Array ( [_id] => Array ( [user] =>
  MongoId Object ( [$id] => 52050d48e654f6342c002d42 )
    [send] => 1
    [open] => 1
    [click] => 2 )
```

Now I need to update corresponding user with the new values (open/send/click) and for each of them add a flag, based on how the values compare with variable X.

How would be a good approach to it without looping through results (this means loading GB of data in memory and doing millions of updates/finds)

Thanks!

Comment: You *might* get better answers on http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions ; ask the moderators to migrate if you think it would be better.

Comment: The common approach would be doing this operation in patches. How to create patches for MongoDB? no idea, yet :)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner -- would you get shot for mentioning nosql over there?

Comment: @WyattBarnett: Apparently not: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nosql  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongodb